# is there a elasticsearch standard solution to load recently changed relational data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following tables which have millions of records and they are changing frequently is there a way to load that data in elasticsearch (for eventual consistency ) with spring boot initially and incrementally?
Tables :
Employee
Role
contactmethod (Phone/email/mobile)
channel
department
Status
Address

Here the document will be like below

```
        {
        "id":1,
        "name": "tom john",
        "Contacts":[
                    {
                    "mobile":123,
                      "type":"MOBILE"
        
                    },
                    {
                "phone":223333
               "type":"PHONE"
        
                }
            ]
        "Address":[
            {
              "city": "New york"
              "ZIP": 12343
              "type":"PERMANENT"
            },
            {
              "city": "New york"
              "ZIP": 12343
              "type":"TEMPORARY"

            }
        ]   
        }
        .. simillar data for ROLE,DEPT etc tables
]
```

How do I make sure that ev.g. mobile number of "tom john" changed in relational DB will be propagated to elasticsearch DB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a background job in your application, which pulls the data from DB(you know when there is change in DB of-course), and based on what you need(filtering, massaging) reindex that in your Elasticsearch index.

or you can use the logstash with JDBC to keep your data in sync, please refer to [elastic blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-keep-elasticsearch-synchronized-with-a-relational-database-using-logstash) on how to do it.

**The first one is a flexible and not out of the box solution, while the second one is out of the box solution, and there are pros and cons of both the approaches and choose what fits best in your use-case.**

Comment: Background job is true but the source application which I have a legacy application (java) which uses oracle DB .Does trigger on any change e.g. mobile or address changes do I need to query elastic search and update respective doc?  Also 2nd options looks does not suit here as I have document formed out of 5-6 tables and any single record changes out of those table how would log stash handle it ?(I suppose it will require plumbing code in process phase). Do you have any sample reference implementation for 1st approach git hub link?

Comment: @Ganesh, yes in your source application, you must be having this functionality already, if not than yeah after updating the DB, you need to update the ES.

Comment: Also it will require some middleware where changes made by source DB need to be pushed and then elastic search app will process them one by one ? What middleware is preferred ?

Comment: @Ganesh, you can use Kafka which is very scalable and reliable, also you will not have data-loss, you can even use their very good integration https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html :)